# Which one is right? "Check out for... online" OR "Check out online for..."?

Tags: grammar

Which one would be right?

Check out for offers online. OR... Check out online for offers.

Comment: The placement of *online* is equally correct, but the placement of *out* is equally incorrect, so I really struggle to say if I should answer "both" or "neither".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like RegDwight's comment, I'd say that you can't simply extend "check out" and have the sentence work. You check *something* out. You could say

> "Check out this website for offers!"

or

> "Check this website out."

Those are correct, but they're not as concise as

> "Check online for offers!"

Even better, you want to say

> "Check our website for offers!"

because it draws their attention to you in a more personal way, which is the point of advertising.

Comment: Full sentese would sound like this: Check out for more offers online! Would it be ok to say like that?

Comment: No. You have to check *something* out. You could say "Check the website out" or "Check out the website", but "online" isn't specific enough a place to use as an object here. I've edited my answer to reflect that.